# Scheduling Conflict: can only detect conflict with exact time

Tags: visual-studio, ms-access

This is the last problem I have to face in for my capstone project, and it's driving me nuts.

Basically, I have to be able to identify if Section/Faculty/Room are all in use when scheduling a subject, to avoid conflicts.

Here's what I've worked on, but so far it can only detect when Room is in use.

I can't figure out how to be able to prevent scheduling that's in-between time periods. For example: First entry would be 7-8:30AM. Second entry would be 7:30 AM to 9 AM. With the former existing, it should reject the latter but I can't figure out how to do that. This is what I've cooked up so far. How would you guys go about this?

```
Public Function DataInUse() As Boolean
    Dim Temp As Boolean
    Temp = False

    If FacultyInUse() = True Then
        MessageBox.Show("Faculty in use.")
        cboFaculty.Focus()
        DisplayFacultyInUse()
        DisplayLabelConflictForFaculty()
        Temp = True

    ElseIf RoomInUse() = True Then
        MessageBox.Show("Room in use.")
        cboRoom.Focus()
        DisplayRoomInUse()
        DisplayLabelConflictForRoom()
        Temp = True
    End If
    Return Temp
End Function

Public Function FacultyInUse() As Boolean
    Dim com As New OleDbCommand(" Select * from qrySubjectOfferring Where cTimeIn >=#" & cboFrom.Text & "# and cTimeOut <=#" & cboTo.Text & "# and Faculty like'" & cboFaculty.Text & "%' and cDay Like '%" & cboDay.Text & "%'", clsCon.con)
    Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = com.ExecuteReader()
    dr.Read()
    If dr.HasRows Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function

Public Function RoomInUse() As Boolean
    Dim com As New OleDbCommand("Select * from qryRoomAvailability WHERE (cTimeIn <=#" & cboFrom.Text & "# AND cTimeOut >=#" & cboFrom.Text & "# AND Room = '" & cboRoom.Text & "' AND cDay = '" & cboDay.Text & "') OR (cTimeIn <=#" & cboTo.Text & "# AND cTimeOut >=#" & cboTo.Text & "# AND Room = '" & cboRoom.Text & "' AND cDay = '" & cboDay.Text & "') OR (cTimeIn >= #" & cboFrom.Text & "# AND cTimeOut <= #" & cboTo.Text & "# AND Room = '" & cboRoom.Text & "' AND cDay = '" & cboDay.Text & "') ", clsCon.con)
    Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = com.ExecuteReader()
    dr.Read()
    If dr.HasRows Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function

Public Function SubjectAlreadyOffered(sSubject As String) As Boolean
    Dim com As New OleDbCommand("Select * from qrySubjectOfferring Where Subject LIKE '%" & sSubject & "%'", clsCon.con)
    Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = com.ExecuteReader()
    dr.Read()
    If dr.HasRows Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: If it works for RoomInUse why are you using a different SQL clause for FacultyInUse 'Where cTimeIn >=#" & cboFrom.Text & "# and cTimeOut <=#" & cboTo.Text & "#'

Comment: The only thing that works for RoomInUse is if they have the same cTimeIn and cTimeout, say if first entry was 7:00AM to 8:00AM second entry 7:30AM to 9AM, it still saves when it shouldn't

Comment: You should clarify in your question - that's not what's implied by "but so far it can only detect when Room is in use"

Answer (score 0):

Try simplifying your SQL to use Between clause and eliminate all entries where the From or To are in existing entries

**In your RoomInUse() function**

```
Dim strSQL as String

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM qryRoomAvailability WHERE " & _
    " Room = '" & cboRoom.Text & "' AND cDay = '" & cboDay.Text & "'" & _   
    " AND NOT (#" & cboFrom.Text "# BETWEEN [" & cTimeIn & "] AND [" & cTimeOut & "])" & _
    " AND NOT (#" & cboTo.Text "# BETWEEN [" & cTimeIn & "] AND [" & cTimeOut & "])"

Dim com As New OleDbCommand(strSQL, clsCon.con)
```